# are there places that can duplicate a vanity mirror? or places to re silver an old mirror?

Tags: mirror

my vanity mirror is really old and you can tell it needs to be resilvered. I read online that the price can be more expensive than just buying a new mirror, but I was wondering if there are places where I can take my mirror and they can just give me an exact new one? also places that resilver as well so I can see which option is best for me budget wise.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to contribute here.

Comment: The only way resilvering is going to make sense is if the mirror is in an ornate shape with complex beveling.  That work can be very expensive.  Regular mirror glass is cheap.

Comment: Beveled or flat glass? Rectangular or curvy? Flat and rectangular can be bought to size at any decent glass shop. Resilvering at home used to be practical, but the chemicals needed have pretty much disappeared since fot us regular folk since 9/11. If you send the glass out, it will almost certainly be aluminized. There are quite a few companies, but most specialize in telescopt mirrors.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the actual mirror can be removed from the frame, getting a replacement custom-cut mirror shouldn't be too hard. Finding a place that can do re-silvering sounds more difficult and more expensive. It can technically be done yourself, but is probably more trouble than it's worth, and also requires removing the actual mirror from the frame.

Finding a place that sells custom-cut glass and mirrors would need to be done locally; this isn't an Internet type of thing.

Comment: e.g. Window repair shop. They might have a mirror of the right size, or that could be cut down, in stock, or use an inexpensive mirror from a department store.